# Derivation of "inside address" recipient of a letter

Tags: derivation

Does anybody know the derivation of the word "inside address" as a part of a business letter also called recipient-address ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are essentially the same thing, except the **inside address** is *inside* the letter, not on the envelope (the envelope has the recipient’s address and optionally the return-address). If the envelope has a window, the “inside address” can be seen from the outside through the envelope window.

This [article](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/business-letter-addressee-etiquette-22754.html) describes it really well:

> All business letters should include the address of the recipient,
>   called the inside address, near the top. Type the address about an
>   inch below the date line, on the left side of the letter. Include the
>   person's full name, if you know it, as well as the business name.

Or as in this [page](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/writing-help/how-to-lay-out-a-letter) from ODO:

> The recipient’s address, also called the inside address, includes the
>   name and address of the recipient of your letter. It may be omitted in
>   informal and social semi-formal letters. For other letters, type it
>   two lines below the date. In all formats, it is left justified.

Comment: The reason for including the 'inside address' even when not using a window envelope is that the recipient can be identified easily from the file copy. Before word processors were developed letters were typed using carbon paper and the carbon copy was filed for future reference. Without the inside address identifying the recipient sorting out file copies would have been almost impossible. I suspect that window envelopes were invented to save work by making use of the pre-existing inside address rather than the inside address developing to make use of window envelopes.